# What's it called when you get a type of award because you didn't get the award you were supposed to get?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's it called when you get a type of award because you didn't get the award you were supposed to get?

Let's say someone was trying to get an award, and they tried really hard, but they didn't end up getting it. But, because people felt bad for them that they didn't get it, the person was given a different award called a(n) ___ award, meaning "Hey, you didn't do it, but here's this instead, because at least you got something."

Comment: Not a prize/award, but a common expression for someone who nearly made it (ie stronger than just a 'participation award') is 'Honorable Mention'

Comment: It would help to differentiate whether the person very narrowly missed out (e.g. 2 exceptional candidates far above the rest of the field but only one prize), or if they missed by miles but are being rewarded anyway (tried hard and showed spirit but had no aptitude). Different circumstances mean different terms.

Comment: This can go a while 'nother way. I've seen a new prize created out of thin air for an original idea never before seen in a contest that had a high creative aspect.

Comment: In children’s sports up to high school and maybe a little beyond, there’s the concept of a “ ooaches’ award”, which can be given to an athlete who has succeeded in some special way, such as overcoming an injury, improving their game, or helping the team as a whole.  So long as these are handed out in small numbers, they provide important recognition to those who don’t win for the most goals or the fastest times

Comment: Montgomery Burns Award for Outstanding Achievement in the Field of Excellence

Comment: **pity award** - what even is *"tried really hard but didn't get it... felt bad?"*. It's called competition. Someone tried harder and won, others lost!

Comment: @CodeAngry Trying harder than everybody else definitely does not guarantee a win.

Comment: “**Experience** is what you get if you don’t get what you wanted”. But that’s probably not what you wanted…

Comment: A Pandering Award? People should learn about competition the hard way. You'll encourage them far more by giving them nothing and teaching them the process of being better next time; disappointment is a part of life - learning that lesson is reward in itself on some level.. A lesson that's sadly missing from the modern world

Comment: @mcalex What's that "participation award", please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin see [Laurel's answer.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/578507/27202)

Comment: Thinking about it, the closest metaphor might be the Best Actress Oscar. The Academy Awards are notorious for repeatedly giving that trophy to the woman who deserved to win the year before.

Comment: You seem to be referring to a situation in which the prize for the runner-up is an afterthought. Is that what you intended?
In Spanish, we use a Latin expression for a not-an-afterthought prize: Accésit, meaning (he or she) 'came near'. I think it's usually a diploma, nothing substantial.

Answer (score 167):

A non-winner might be awarded a

> **consolation prize**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A prize given to a competitor who just fails to win or who has come last.
> *A two-week holiday in Cape Town was the consolation prize.*

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/consolation_prize).

The word [consolation](https://www.lexico.com/definition/consolation) itself means

> The comfort received by a person after a loss or disappointment.

Comment: When the consolationprize is a two-week holiday in Cape Town, I really wonder what the main prize was :o

Comment: @infinitezero - probably a _one_ week holiday in Cape Town. I'm joking of course - Cape Town's lovely (apart from the bit around the station).

Comment: Back in the day the consolation prize from a game show was often the home version of the game.

Comment: @barbecue I remember lots of Rice A Roni and Lee's Press-On Nails.

Comment: @Weather Vane Broadly yes, of course, yet how does "A two-week holiday (where) was the consolation prize" help to explain anything? I'm sorry if I seem pedantic, and I suggest that example is wholly useless - as are so many similar examples in modern dictionaries.

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly. That states a fact and it neither explains nor illustrates anything. How, exactly, would the same grammar or syntax not apply to the 15th prize? In this context how, exactly, does "a two-week holiday…" even hint at the difference between major and consolation prizes?

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you should should recognise the obvious truth of what I said, and explain why you seem to object?

Comment: No. This answer offers a well-known term that is used in the context of the question asked, and is supported with dictionary references.

Answer (score 11):

This is a participation award/trophy/ribbon. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participation_trophy):

> A participation trophy is a trophy given to children (usually) who participate in a sporting event but do not finish in first, second or third place, and so would not normally be eligible for a trophy. It is frequently associated with millennials, those of Generation Y.

When it's not an official reward, you can also use the expression "got an A for effort". From [Farlex via TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+for+effort):

> A verbal acknowledgement of appreciation for attempting a task, even if it did not produce a successful result.
>
> > You forgot to sand the wood before you painted it, but I'll give you an A for effort since you tried to help.

I have also heard names for an award for last place, but those aren't typically given as [a pat on the back](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20pat%20on%20the%20back). See [What is a "prize" for last place called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/283337/191178)

Comment: "Participation trophy" seems to be the most recent euphemism for "consolation prize", which was what it was called in N. Illinois when I was learning English.

Comment: @JohnLawler I was posting an answer before seeing your comment.

Comment: I thought this was what it's called when *everyone* gets a prize. This is generally only common in children's sports, supposedly as an esteem-building process.

Comment: It isn't a participation prize because the question suggests a genuine effort and achievement, but not good enough to win.  The answer is correct in itself, but misses the intent of the question.

Answer (score 9):

Weather Vane’s answer, **consolation prize**, is what first came to my mind. You could also say that the judges **made it up to** the recipient for not giving her the award she truly deserved.  A **consolation prize** is always of lower value, but we **make up for** not giving someone a prize he deserved by giving him another of equal value.

An award for the second-best finisher is also a **runner-up award** or **silver medal**.  An American might sometimes ironically call a person who comes in second **Miss Congeniality**, the title of the runner-up in the Miss America beauty pageant.  Someone who always does well but never wins is “always a bridesmaid, never a bride.”  Thus, a special award given to honor someone who never won the annual award is a **bridesmaid award**.  Or, more politely, a **lifetime achievement award**.

In some other contexts, we would use **make-up** as an adjective. When a referee sees a replay, realizes he got a call wrong, and calls the next play wrong for the other team to make up for it, balance the scales, and even things out, that’s a **make-up call**.  We don’t say that for awards, though.  A “make-up award” is an award for cosmetics.

This is not a **participation trophy**,  because everyone gets one of those.  It’s also not a **booby prize**.  Those are given out mockingly, although [it is possible to accept one with grace and dignity, or at least good humor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-7s_yeQuDg)  It’s not a **wooden spoon** either, as that is for last place, not the person who should have won.

Other commenters have suggested, **replacement trophy**, and that could work.  It could be confused for a new trophy commissioned to replace one that has been lost or stolen.

##### ETA:

It’s not a well-known saying, but thinking about it, the best metaphor for this in American culture might be the Academy Award for Best Actress.  The Oscars are notorious for repeatedly giving it to the actress who most people felt deserved to win the year before, when they voted to give it instead to the woman who’d deserved to win the year before that.

Comment: I have never seen the phrase Booby Prize before. Where does that come from?

Comment: @WordyBirdy It’s common here in America. According to *The Oxford Dictionary of Etymology*, the first recorded citation is from 1884: “At the end of every session the dominie had the satirical custom of presenting his tawse [a corporal punishment implement used for educational discipline] as a "booby-prize" to some idle or stupid lout whom he picked out as meriting this distinction so that next time they met he might start fresh and fair with new pair for a new set of classes.”

Comment: Consolation award isn't a perfect phrase but probably as a native speaker, it and "substitute award" are  closest in meaning to the OP. Specifically, it doesn't imply they got good or bad performance, were a failure or runner up. They simply didn't get the award they should have been given, *whatever it may have been* .....

Comment: @Stilez To me (on the west coast of the US), a “consolation prize”goes to someone who came in second, or sometimes to the top few contenders who didn’t win. I don’t think I’ve ever heard “consolation award.” “Substitute award” might work, but I don’t think it’s common here.

Comment: @Davislor - I think y9u are probably right, now I think about it....

Answer (score 5):

- Runner Up Prize
- Runner Up Award

https://boardgamestips.com/popular/what-is-runner-up-prize/

> What is runner up prize? English Language Learners Definition of
> runner-up : a person or team that does not win first place in a
> competition but that does well enough to get a prize especially : a
> person or team that finishes in second place. See the full definition
> for runner-up in the English Language Learners Dictionary. runner-up.
> noun.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/runner-up

> noun, plural run·ners-up. the competitor, player, or team finishing in
> second place, as in a race, contest, or tournament. runners-up, the
> competitors who do not win a contest but who place ahead of the
> majority of the contestants and share in prizes or honors, as those
> who place second, third, and fourth, or in the top ten.

Comment: The OP isn't a runner up, here.  They just (for unknown reasons) got an award because they weren't given **the one they should have got**.

Comment: @Stilez "or honors" you don't have to get a shiny piece of metal to get recognized. Plenty of runner ups who can say "I was nominated for an Emmy but didn't get it". They are runner ups who, by many arguments, should have won the Emmy over that other guy/gal.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the award. I'd start with calling it a substitute, anything else is more denigrating variants of it really.

E.g. I know of people who got awarded the second highest military honours during the Vietnam war because the people writing the citations were aware that because of the political situation and/or rank of the soldier involved they'd not pass the political process involved with granting the congressional medal of honour. I'd not call that a booby price, participation trophy, or some other denigrating thing at all and neither does the US military (these people are awarded almost the same honours and ceremony when visiting a US military base as any CMH recipient for example).

Especially a participation trophy is something worthless that you get simply for taking part. A campaign ribbon in the military would be such, for example.

Comment: "workaround" would be accurate if the award were earned but cannot be awarded based on a technicality (or for political reasons) and in no way denigrates the recipient.  Perhaps it speaks poorly of the rules-writer.  But the question is clearly not talking about this scenario where the rules were defective, but where the person didn't earn the award but will anyway receive a prize for the effort.

Comment: Substitute award isn't a perfect phrase but probably as a native speaker, it and "consolation award" are  closest in meaning to the OP. Specifically, it doesn't imply they got good or bad performance, were a failure or runner up. They simply didn't get the award they should have been given, *whatever it may have been* .....

Comment: @Stilez correct, and there's no single word to describe that scenario so you have to come up with a descriptive term.

Answer (score 3):

An almost-winner might receive an

> **honorable mention**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> a commendation given to a candidate in an examination or competition who is not awarded a prize

From [Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=honorable%20mention)

One might consider that honorable mentions would have won the award, or placed in the top three, if the eventual winner had not entered.

Therefore an honorable mention would equate to a fourth/fifth/sixth place if there were awards for first, second, and third place.

Answer (score 1):

**booby prize**

> **Definition of *booby prize***
>
> 1: an award for the poorest performance in a game or competition
>
> 2: an acknowledgment of notable inferiority
>
> **Examples of *booby prize* in a Sentence**
>
> **Recent Examples on the Web**
>
> > And a *booby prize* awaits for whichever team happens to finish second:
> > a possible date with England in London in the round of 16. — Joshua
> > Robinson, *WSJ,* 22 June 2021
> >
> > Right now, that seems like more a *booby prize* than a reward. — Ann
> > Killion, *San Francisco Chronicle,* 6 Mar. 2021
>
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/booby%20prize)

Example sentence:

> I win 2nd place booby prize in Loser pool if the OH teams win. — King Hippo. Admin. October 13, 2019 12:04 pm [[DOOR FLIES OPEN]](https://doorfliesopen.com/2019/10/13/your-meanwhile-back-in-america-sunday-nfl-football-open-thread/comment-page-1/)

Comment: It’s important to realize that a “booby prize” is given out ironically, and receiving it is an insult. Which it is still possible to accept with grace and dignity. [Or at least good humor.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-7s_yeQuDg)

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your comments, but what Joshua Robinson was, if I understand him, talking about the 2021 European football championships, and saying that the second-place finisher in group F would have to play England next, in their home stadium. And this was really no prize at all.

Comment: That is, the second quote was saying that the second-place finisher in that group would get an ostensible prize (advancement to the next round of the tournament), but it was really a punishment for losing (because the match-up was so unfavorable), not a prize anyone would want.

Comment: [*Booby*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/booby) here is not that kind of booby.

Comment: An alternative to 'Booby Prize' would be the 'Wooden Spoon', which is also (generally) given, ironically, to the last place position.

Comment: No, the OP is not referring to an alternative award for visibly bad performace.....

Comment: Nobody is discussing anyone's friends here. So no need to confuse the issue. As you surely understand, you described a booby prize (correctly) as going to poorest (worst) performance. But the OP isn't asking about others words for visibly bad (worst) performance.  That's all.

Answer (score 1):

**Wooden Spoon**

A wooden spoon is an award that is given to an individual or team that has come last in a competition.

It was presented originally at the University of Cambridge as a kind of booby prize (see other answer) awarded by the students to the person who achieved the lowest exam marks but still earned a third-class degree in the Mathematical Tripos.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_spoon_(award))

Comment: Another one of those from the world of sports is the “Mr. Irrelevant” title given (as a joke by sports columnists at first, but now there’s an informal award ceremony in the parking lot outside) to the player picked last in the NFL Draft. This isn’t well-known enough to be used without explanation, but some years’ “Mr. Irrelevant” have gotten endorsement contracts because of it. One joked that everybody always remembered that he was in the NFL, and won some kind of award, but not which one, and one person even thought he was “Mr. Omnipotent.”

Comment: No, the OP is not referring to an alternative award for visibly bad performace.....

Comment: So the worst passing performance. But like I said,the OP isn't asking about an award signifying worst performance of any kind, passing or failing as it may be.

Answer (score -1):

### Bauble

An award that is given which is nevertheless lacking in real weight and significance is sometimes referred to as a 'Bauble'. For example, in [this news article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-58575894) Dominic Raab was reported to be appointed to the constitutionally almost meaningless role of 'Deputy Prime Minister' of the UK. His new role is described thusly:

> But even with the bauble of deputy prime minister as part of his title [...], Mr Raab, the now former foreign secretary, is a less senior figure in the government.